# SPSS merge datasets with add variables only links 1 case

Tags: spss

I have the following syntax to merge two datasets. I expect that the resulting dataset (test1) contains 5 cases with 4 of them (2 to 5) a value in variable set2.

The result I am getting is dataset test1 with 5 cases but only 1 of them (case with id 5) has a value in variable set2.

Do I need to contact my ICT department, or am I misunderstanding something about merging data in SPSS. I am used to working with SAS, R and SQL, but need to help someone with a data merging within SPSS

```
 INPUT PROGRAM.
LOOP id=1 to 5.
END CASE.
END LOOP.
END FILE.
END INPUT PROGRAM.
COMPUTE set1 = RV.NORMAL(1,1).
EXECUTE.
DATASET NAME test1.
INPUT PROGRAM.
LOOP id=2 to 5.
END CASE.
END LOOP.
END FILE.
END INPUT PROGRAM.
COMPUTE set2 = RV.NORMAL(1,1).
EXECUTE.
DATASET NAME test2.

DATASET ACTIVATE test1. 
STAR JOIN 
  /SELECT t0.set1, t1.set2 
  /FROM * AS t0 
  /JOIN 'test2' AS t1 
    ON t0.id=t1.id 
  /OUTFILE FILE=*.
```

results in:

```
id      set1    set2
1,00    1,74    
2,00    1,58    
3,00    1,01    
4,00    ,12 
5,00    2,52    ,79
```

SPSS version 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run the syntax you provide I get the desired results (and not what you indicate):

[image]

If it continues to fail (after contacting SPSS support), try using [`MATCH FILES`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_match_files.htm):

```
DATASET ACTIVATE test1. 
SORT CASES BY ID.
DATASET ACTIVATE test2. 
SORT CASES BY ID.

MATCH FILES FILE=test1 /FILE=test2 /BY ID.
DATASET NAME Restult.
```

Comment: Match files works like it should. I'll contact SPSS for the main issue.

Comment: I can't recall why and under what situations `STAR JOIN` would be more beneficial than `MATCH FILES` other than knowing that `STAR JOIN` doesn't require the datasets to be sorted by matching keys. `STAR JOIN` is a newly added command to provide SQL like joins but may well have some bugs in its infancy. I am using v24, if that may explain any differences?

Comment: Early versions of STAR JOIN had some problems, so I would recommend using MATCH FILES.